# PowerShell - Remove-DnsServerSigningKey -KeyId $key.KeyId -ZoneName $zonename -Force

Tags: powershell, dns, key

The following does simply not work:

```
Remove-DnsServerSigningKey -KeyId $key.KeyId -ZoneName $zonename -Force
```

Where $zonename is a valid zone, and the key-id exists and is valid.
This command works if i first unsign a zone, but i want to do this just after a resign.

Logic:

- grab all current zone signing keys
- Add one new ZSK
- Resign the zone with the new ZSK
- Sleep for 3 seconds (just for a grace period)
- Loop through all previous keys *(at this point, the new key is not in the list)*

  - Delete previous key

When trying to delete previous keys i get:

```
Remove-DnsServerSigningKey : Failed to delete the signing key __[Key-ID]__ for the zone __[Key-ID]__ on server __[Server-addr]__ Please check 
extended error for additional details.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dnssec.ps1:79 char:13
+             Remove-DnsServerSigningKey -KeyId $key.KeyId -ZoneName $zonename -Fo ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (__[Key-Id]__:root/Microsoft/...erverSigningKey) [Remove-DnsServerSigningKey], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 9119,Remove-DnsServerSigningKey
```

The code looks like this:

```
function resign {
    param(
        [string]$zonename
    )
    $zonename + " <- Re-Signing"

    ## Grab all current keys (incl active ones)
    $keys = Get-DnsServerSigningKey -ZoneName $zonename

    $zonename + " <- Creating new ZSK"
    #Add a new ZSK 
    Add-DnsServerSigningKey -ZoneName $zonename -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -CryptoAlgorithm RsaSha256 -Type ZoneSigningKey

    #Resign the zone with the newly added key 
    Invoke-DnsServerZonesign -ZoneName $zonename –DoResign -Force

    Start-Sleep -s 1

    # After the resign, we delete all previous ZONE signing keys (but keep KSK)
    $zonename + " <- Removing ZSKeys"
    foreach ($key in $keys) {
        if ($key.KeyType -eq "ZoneSigningKey") {
            Remove-DnsServerSigningKey -ComputerName 127.0.0.1 -ZoneName $zonename -KeyId $key.KeyId -Force
        }
    }
}
```

Notabel might be that if i Unsign the zone completely and run the same delete-keys code, it works. It's just when resigning a zone that it doesn't work.
The key i'm trying to delete is of type ZoneSigningKey and not KeySigningKey (verified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by, in short, removing the signed zone,
deleting the old ZSK and keeping the old KSK, generating a new ZSK and signed the zone again.

Basically i called unsign and sign again within resign.. it's ugly and not the way it's intended to work.. but it works..